# variables set in a file not reflected in the shell

Tags: bash

In a file script, I have following commands

```
export CIA_HOME=$PWD
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/cia_modules:/opt/autotest/data/scripts
```

Note: There is no `#!/bin/bash` in the first line

when I run `./script` and the do 
`echo $CIA_HOME`,  it doesn't print any thing.

If I do `. ./script`, it works.

My question is why it didn't work in the first case even though it didn't launch a subshell.

Comment: see for example [Why doesn't "cd" work in a shell script?](//askubuntu.com/q/481715)

Comment: #!/bin/bash in first line tells which interpreter you would like to run the script. The absence of this just means that your script will run with the same interpreter as the parent shell, not that it wont run in a sub-shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run your script like `./script` it's going to run in a subshell so the variable only is available to that subshell and child of that shell.

```
$ nano a.sh # create a script ( for test put sleep 1000 in script )
$ chmod +x a.sh # make it executable 
$ ./a.sh & # run it
[1] 8929 # pay attention to its pid
$ echo $$ # check your current shell id
8742
```

now let's check it using `pstree`:

```
$ pstree -sp `pgrep sleep`
bash(8742)───bash(8929)───sleep(8930)
```